# Automatically Inserting text into webpage in UIWebview

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode

There is a mobile version of a site I would like to use for an app, and it asks for the server login, the username, and the password. I want the server to be automatically inserted when the tab is selected/the app is loaded. I have tried several things related to javascript but they have not worked.

Comment: What's tht site? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What *exactly* have you tried so far? Post the code

Comment: the site is http://mtouch.pragmasql.com/MoodleLogin.mvc/Login

Comment: I have tried several methods using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString but I can't figure out where to put it or how to set it to find the certain text field and then insert the text

Comment: this is what i am trying at the moment and it is not working          -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('Url').value = 'Hello World'"];

}